# Filtering empty values from an API in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, uikit

I'm trying to filter out empty and null values from an api in a json format in swift(UIKit).
The full data returns look like below but sometimes can contain null or empty values in the `characteristic` key. There is always going to be the same amount of keys.

```
//Cat

{
"breedname": "Persian",
"picture": "https://catimage.random.png",
"characteristic1": "Shy",
"characteristic2": "Hungry all the time"
"characteristic3": "Likes apples"
"characteristic4": "Grey color"
"characteristic5": "likes chin scratches"
 }

{
"breedname": "Bengal",
"picture": "https://catimage.random.png",
"characteristic1": "Active",
"characteristic2": "Adventurous"
"characteristic3": ""
"characteristic4": ""
"characteristic5": ""
 }

{
"breedname": "ragdoll",
"picture": "https://catimage.random.png",
"characteristic1": "Fiestey",
"characteristic2": "sharp claws"
"characteristic3": null
"characteristic4": null
"characteristic5": null
 }
```

In order to filter null and empty values before showing in the UI, I have a Decodable class like below and a custom init class with the `decodeifPresent` method which changes null values to nill. However for empty values I just created a method which converts empty string values to nill. I'm not sure if there are better ways to handle empty and null data and filtering them out? I refer to all the Decodable keys in the UI so I cannot simply delete the keys themselves.

```
struct Cat: Decodable {
    
    let breedName: String
    let picture: String
    let characteristic1 : String?
    let characteristic2 : String?
    let characteristic3 : String?
    let characteristic4 : String?
    let characteristic5 : String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case breedName
        case picture
        case characteristic1
        case characteristic2
        case characteristic3
        case characteristic4
        case characteristic5
}

    func checkEmpty(s: String?) -> String? {
        if s == "" {
            return nil
        }
        return s
    }

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.breedName= try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .breedName)
        self.picture = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .picture)
        self.characteristic1 = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .characteristic1)

        self.characteristic2 = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .characteristic2)
        self.characteristic3 = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .characteristic3)
        self.characteristic4 = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .characteristic4)
        self.characteristic5 = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .characteristic5)

self.characteristic1 = checkEmpty(s: self.characteristic1)
self.characteristic2 = checkEmpty(s: self.characteristic2)
self.characteristic3 = checkEmpty(s: self.characteristic3)
self.characteristic4 = checkEmpty(s: self.characteristic4)
self.characteristic5 = checkEmpty(s: self.characteristic5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to check for empty in a function defined in an extension to String

```
extension String {
    func emptyAsNil() -> String? {
        self.isEmpty ? nil : self
    }
}
```

Then you could do all in one step in the init

```
self.characteristic1 = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .characteristic1)?.emptyAsNil()
```

But perhaps a better solution is to gather all those properties in a collection like an array or a dictionary. Here I have chosen an array

```
struct Cat: Decodable {
    let breedName: String
    let picture: String
    var characteristics: [String]
}
```

and then in the init we add only non-nil, non-empty values to the array

```
if let value = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .characteristic1), !value.isEmpty {
    characteristics.append(value)
}
```

or another way is to loop over the keys

```
let keys: [CodingKeys] = [.characteristic1,
                              .characteristic2,
                              .characteristic3,
                              .characteristic4,
                              .characteristic5]

for key in keys {
    if let value = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: key), !value.isEmpty {
        characteristics.append(value)
    }
}
```